# Print epoch time before and after every issued command in bash

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, command

I am trying to modify my `~/.bash_profile` so that the Unix epoch time automatically gets printed before and after the execution of every issued command in bash, like so:

```
[prompt]$ some-maybe-multiline-command
Started execution at: <epoch time>
...
<stuff printed out by some-maybe-multiline-command, if any>
...
Finished execution at: <epoch time>
[prompt]$
```

How can I achieve this? Ideally, I want to have minimum side effects while doing so (e.g. I do not want this change to affect too many logs if possible); it should ideally only affect what I see on the terminal screen.

Thanks a lot in advance!

I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/562018/run-every-bash-command-through-a-function-or-wrapper) Unix StackExchange, and tried to adopt it to my situation; but I haven't been successful so far..

Adding `trap <command> DEBUG` into the `~/.bash_profile` is the closest thing to a solution that I found so far. However, I am not sure how to make the `<command>` be aware of whether it is being executed before or after the execution of the issued command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bash's `PS0` <sup>(requires bash 4.4+)</sup> and `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

According to `man bash`:

> - PROMPT_COMMAND
>
>   If this variable is set, and is an array, the value of each set element is executed as a command prior  to issuing  each primary prompt.  If this is set but not an array variable, its value is used as a command to execute instead.
> - PS0
>
>   The value of this parameter is expanded and displayed by  interactive  shells  after reading a command and before the command is executed.

Example:

```bash
PS0='>>> $( date +%s )\n'
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo "<<< $( date +%s )"'
```

```
$ echo hello world; sleep 2
>>> 1686801897
hello world
<<< 1686801899
```

Comment: This looks like the best possible solution to my question; thank you! I unfortunately forgot to mention that I want to calculate the total duration right after printing the execution end time, like so:

```

$ echo hello world; sleep 2

>>> 1686801897

hello world

<<< 1686801899

<<<     Total execution time: 2

```

How can I do that by using `PS0` and `PROMPT_COMMAND` in the way you described? Thanks again!

Comment: in PS0 you can save the begin time to a tmp file, then in PROMPT_COMMAND you can calculate the time diff.

Answer (score 0):

`trap command DEBUG` execute the command before the execution. So you need something else for after.

One solution could be a combination of PS1 and trap

```bash
function showBefore(){
    printf "started at %s\n" $(date +"%s")
}
trap showBefore DEBUG
export PS1="Ended at \D{%s}> "
```

Example output

```
Ended at 1686798230> sleep 10
started at 1686798232
Ended at 1686798242>
```

You could also use `PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "Ended at %s\n" $(date +"%s")'` instead of PS1. Both occur when the prompt is displayed, that is just after the previous command is finished. But then (as shown in the link you have seen) the `showBefore` function becomes more complicated, because the execution of the `PROMPT_COMMAND` will also trigger the TRAP. Which is not aesthetic (tho you can ignore all the "started at lines" but the first)